# Is there a way to upload to S3 using ruby net::ssh

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, net-ssh

I want to remotely upload a file that is on some hosts using Net::SSH

The file is really big, so I don't want to download because it takes too much time, those hosts are EC2 machines on AWS

```
Net::SSH.start(final_host, "ubuntu") do |ssh|
    #download the tar file to local
    ssh.scp.download!(remote, local)
    #upload file to s3
    bucket.objects[(Time.now-36000).to_date.to_s + key].write(:file => local)
end
```

I use this code to upload the file, but when it have been downloaded

Comment: Can you share some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I share the code I'm using

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the [AWS Ruby SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) or [Fog gem](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws)?

Comment: The bucket.objects is an AWS Ruby SDK object to upload to S3, but I do in local

Comment: You ever figure something out?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have SSH access to your EC2 instance, you can run a command on it to upload to S3 directly from there. If you have `s3cmd` installed on it, it would be something like

```
Net::SSH.start(final_host, 'ubuntu') do |ssh|
  s3_name = (Time.now - 36000).to_date.to_s + key
  ssh.exec "s3cmd put #{remote} s3://#{bucket}/#{s3_name}"
end
```

Or, you can put a Ruby script on the instance using the AWS SDK like you are now, and run that:

```
ssh.exec "ruby upload_to_s3.rb #{remote}"
```